# SQL- Employee vacation dates tracking

Tags: sql

```
Emp id start date end date 
1. 1/14/18. 1/4/18 
1. 1/8/18. 1/8/18 
1. 1/11/18. 1/11/18 
1. 1/12/18. 1/12/18 
1. 1/13/18. 1/13/18 
1. 1/14/18. 1/14/18 
1. 1/15/18. 1/15/18 
1. 1/16/18. 1/16/18 
2. 1/1/18 1/13/18
```

I need if employee #1 goes contines from above table for over 5 days i need to get alerts. So from row 3 to 8 should count . First two rows should not count. Please help in sql. May be thinking to create loop .

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: How do you define the order of such data?  Order isn't guaranteed in the tables so how do I know emp_ID 1 on 1/14/18 doesn't go with one one later?

Comment: i didn't define. that is the way employee vacation table is setup as

Answer (score 0):

You can identify groups of adjacent dates by subtracting a sequence number.  The exact syntax depends on the database, but something like this.

Then, you can count within the group:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by emp_id, grp) as cnt
from (select t.*, 
             (start_date -
              row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by start_date) * interval '1 day'
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can use this as a subquery and add a where clause, such as `where cnt >= 5` to get the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gordon.
it did work but now i want to put this query in loop using cursor so it will read each record by employee id. i did put but same 6 records are repeating . i think something is wrong with loop they way i had declare:

```
DECLARE @emp as varchar(20);
Declare @start as Date;
Declare @end as Date;
--Declare @date as Date;
DECLARE pstar2 CURSOR FOR
SELECT ApproveTime.[Employee ID],ApproveTime.[Start Date],ApproveTime.[End Date] 
from ApproveTime 
--where ApproveTime.[Employee ID]='JUF0036419' and
--ApproveTime.[Start Date]=ApproveTime.[End Date] 
--ApproveTime.[Employee ID]='36419'

open pstar2
--while loop
--EXIT when c1%NOTFOUND;
 FETCH next from pstar2 into @emp, @start, @end
 while (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
 begin
select 
       count(*) over (partition by ApproveTime.[Employee ID], grp) as cnt, *
from (select t.*, 
             (t.[Start Date] -
              row_number() over (partition by t.[Employee ID] order by t.[Start Date]) * 1
             ) as grp
      from approvetime t
     ) approvetime where ApproveTime.[Employee ID]='36419'
     and  (ApproveTime.[Start Date] >='2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' and ApproveTime.[End Date]<='2018-01-31 00:00:00.000')
 print @emp 
 print @start
 print @end

 end
 --end
close pstar2
DEALLOCATE pstar2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gordon. it did work but now i want to put this query in loop using cursor so it will read each record by employee id. i did put but same 6 records are repeating . i think something is wrong with loop they way i had declare:

```
DECLARE @emp as varchar(20);
Declare @start as Date;
Declare @end as Date;
--Declare @date as Date;
DECLARE pstar2 CURSOR FOR
SELECT ApproveTime.[Employee ID],ApproveTime.[Start Date],ApproveTime.[End Date] 
from ApproveTime 
--where ApproveTime.[Employee ID]='JUF0036419' and
--ApproveTime.[Start Date]=ApproveTime.[End Date] 
--ApproveTime.[Employee ID]='36419'

open pstar2
--while loop
--EXIT when c1%NOTFOUND;
 FETCH next from pstar2 into @emp, @start, @end
 while (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
 begin
select 
       count(*) over (partition by ApproveTime.[Employee ID], grp) as cnt, *
from (select t.*, 
             (t.[Start Date] -
              row_number() over (partition by t.[Employee ID] order by t.[Start Date]) * 1
             ) as grp
      from approvetime t
     ) approvetime where ApproveTime.[Employee ID]='36419'
     and  (ApproveTime.[Start Date] >='2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' and ApproveTime.[End Date]<='2018-01-31 00:00:00.000')
 print @emp 
 print @start`enter code here`
 print @end

 end
 --end
close pstar2
DEALLOCATE pstar2
```